# Dos elmentos en foreach en c#

Tags: c#, foreach

nuevamente. Lo que pretende el programa es que puedas modificar el titulo y parrafo de una tarjtea mediante la posicion del arreglo y sobre los titulos, todo correcto. Pero quisiera saber si hay alguna manera en c# de agregarle 2 instrucciones al foreach ya que si meto un foreach dentro de otro se repiten las iteraciones y me genera muchas tarjetas y yo solo quiero 10. Les dejo el codigo espero me puedan ayudar

```
 private void InitComponent()
    {
        int o = 0;
        int i = 0;
        var titulo = new string[10];
        titulo[0] = "titulo1";
        titulo[1] = "titulo2";
        titulo[2] = "titulo3";
        titulo[3] = "titulo4";
        titulo[4] = "titulo5";
        titulo[5] = "titulo6";
        titulo[6] = "titulo7";
        titulo[7] = "titulo8";
        titulo[8] = "titulo9";
        titulo[9] = "titulo10";

        var parrafo = new string[10];
        parrafo[0] = "parrafo1";
        parrafo[1] = "parrafo2";
        parrafo[2] = "parrafo3";
        parrafo[3] = "parrafo4";
        parrafo[4] = "parrafo5";
        parrafo[5] = "parrafo6";
        parrafo[6] = "parrafo7";
        parrafo[7] = "parrafo8";
        parrafo[8] = "parrafo9";
        parrafo[9] = "parrafo10";

        this._contenedor = new Panel();
        _contenedor.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        _contenedor.Size = new Size(800, 550);
        //_contenedor.BackColor = Color.Black;
        _contenedor.AutoScroll = true;
        this.Controls.Add(_contenedor);

        foreach (var tit in titulo )// aqui meter 2 variables que hagan referencia a los distintos arreglos
        {
            //foreach (var item in parrafo)
            //{ 
            Componentes.Tarjeta tarjeta = new Componentes.Tarjeta(new Size(700, 150), Image.FromHbitmap(Properties.Resources.maxresdefault.GetHbitmap()), "" + tit, "" , new Point(50, (i * 180)));

            Button ubi = new Button()
            {
                Location = new Point(550, 100),
                Text = "Tarjeta" + (i + 1),
                Width = 90,
                Height = 24,
            };
                void Ubi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ubi.Text);
                }
            tarjeta.Controls.Add(ubi);
            tarjeta.AutoScroll = true;
            _contenedor.Controls.Add(tarjeta);
            ubi.Click += Ubi_Click;

                i++;
                if (i>10)
                {
                    break;
                }
            //}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un for en vez de un foreach:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    // titulo[x] accede a los items de título
    // parrafo[x] accede a los items de párrafo
}
```

EDIT: Otra cosa que se me ocurre es que puedes crear una clase que contenga ambos datos:

```
public class TituloYParrafo
{
    public TituloYParrafo(string titulo, string parrafo)
    {
        Titulo = titulo;
        Parrafo = parrafo;
    }

    public string Titulo { get; }
    public string Parrafo { get; }
}
```

Y en tu código:

```
var tituloyParrafo = var new[] 
{
    new TituloYParrafo("Titulo 0", "Parrafo 0"),
    new TituloYParrafo("Titulo 1", "Parrafo 1"),
    // etc...
};

//  ya puedes usar el foreach
foreach (var item in tituloyParrafo)
{
    // item.Titulo para acceder al título
    // item.Parrafo para acceder al párrafo
}
```

O si no quieres crear una clase puedes usar una tupla:

```
var tituloyParrafo = var new[] 
{
    Tuple.Create("Titulo 0", "Parrafo 0"),
    Tuple.Create("Titulo 1", "Parrafo 1"),
    // etc...
};

//  ya puedes usar el foreach
foreach (var item in tituloyParrafo)
{
    // item.Item1 para acceder al título
    // item.Item2 para acceder al párrafo
}
```

La clase Tuple está definida en System.

Comment: Lo tenia con for pero no me recorría los nombres, me dejaba un nombre fijo para todos y la idea es que se editen en el arreglo para que sean diferentes

Comment: Lo tenia con for pero no me recorría los nombres, me dejaba un nombre fijo para todos y la idea es que se editen en el arreglo para que sean diferentes

Comment: ¿puedes poner el código como lo tenías? igual es algo con alguna variable.